# RTF to PDF format convert using java in linux

Tags: java, pdf, rtf, documents4j

I created a Java code to convert RTF format documents to PDF format. Program works properly in windows. But it gives error in linux. Can someone please show me the issue with this code ?

Java code:

```
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputWord = new File("sample.rtf");
        File outputFile = new File("sample.pdf");
        try  {
            InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().build();
            converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.RTF).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I used documents4j version 1.1.3 to implement this code.

Below error gives in linux environment:

```
ERROR com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge - Unable to run script: /tmp/1595252529799-0/word_start1195732765.vbs
org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessInitException: Could not execute [cmd, /S, /C, ""/tmp/1595252529799-0/word_start1195732765.vbs""] in /tmp/1595252529799-0. Error=2, No such file or directory
at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessInitException.newInstance(ProcessInitException.java:80)
at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.invokeStart(ProcessExecutor.java:1002)
at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.startInternal(ProcessExecutor.java:970)
at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:906)
at com.documents4j.conversion.AbstractExternalConverter.runNoArgumentScript(AbstractExternalConverter.java:72)
at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.runNoArgumentScript(AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.java:51)
at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.tryStart(AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.java:34)
at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge.startUp(MicrosoftWordBridge.java:46)
at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge.<init>(MicrosoftWordBridge.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.make(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:30)
at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.makeAll(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:42)
at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.loadConfiguration(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:85)
at com.documents4j.conversion.DefaultConversionManager.<init>(DefaultConversionManager.java:22)
at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.makeConversionManager(LocalConverter.java:79)
at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.<init>(LocalConverter.java:51)
at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter$Builder.build(LocalConverter.java:186)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but maybe your library uses ms-word or a vbs interpreter as a utility which is simply not available on linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `com.documents4j.LocalConverter` object to perform the conversion. According to the [documentation](https://documents4j.com):

> A `LocalConverter` can only be run if:
>
> - The JVM is run on a MS Windows platform that ships with the Microsoft Scripting Host for VBS (this is true for all contemporary
>   versions of MS Windows.
> - MS Word is installed in version 2007 or higher. PDF conversion is only supported when the PDF plugin is installed. The plugin is
>   included into MS Word from Word 2010 and higher.
> - etcetera

Obviously, neither of these prerequisites can be met on a Linux machine.

Your options would appear to be:

- Use `RemoteConverter` to get a remote Windows machine to do the conversion.
- Look for alternative RTF to PDF converter that will run on Linux.